Sending message from worker to main thread in Qt app inside DLL
I have a C++/Qt DLL which is called from a Delphi GUI app, both running on a Windows system exclusively. The DLL creates various worker threads. I want the worker threads to report their result by callback to Delphi app, but not in the context of the worker thread, but of the main thread. The worker thread therefore signals the main thread, which then calls the callback back into the Delphi application. I used two approaches:

Sending a Windows message by PostThreadMessage(). This failed because the messages sent to the main thread are never received.
Sending a custom QEvent by QApplication::postEvent(). This works. The events sent to main thread are received in main thread.

The DLL creates its own QApplication-derived instance, then attaches itself to the enclosing message loop (Delphi GUI application):
void
initDll() {

    /* thread ID of calling application (= Delphi GUI thread) */
    mainThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

    if (auto * app = QCoreApplication::instance(); app == nullptr) {
        /* no instance so far, create one */
        DLL_qtApplicationCreated    = true;

        /* see class declaration / definition of QtMainApp below */
        DLL_qtApplication           = new QtMainApp(qArgc, qArgv);
        /* add Windows message event filter */
        auto * eventFilter = new bcc::dll::WindowsMessageEventFilter();
        DLL_qtApplication->installNativeEventFilter(eventFilter);
        /* need to call processEvents once to make Qt synchronize with Windows event loop */
        QApplication::processEvents();
    }
}

The Windows message event filter:
**
 * Filter receives native Windows messages.
 *
 * Attached to Qt application.
 */
class WindowsMessageEventFilter : public QAbstractNativeEventFilter {

public:
    /**
     * Receives Windows messages.
     *
     * @see QAbstractNativeEventFilter::nativeEventFilter()
     */
    bool
    nativeEventFilter(
            const QByteArray        & eventType,
            void                    * message,
            qintptr                 * result) override {

        assert(eventType.toStdString() == "windows_dispatcher_MSG"s || eventType.toStdString() == "windows_generic_MSG"s);

        /* receives no events unfortunately ... */
        const auto * msg = static_cast<MSG *>(message);
        receivedMessages123.emplace_back(*msg);
    }

    std::vector<MSG>        receivedMessages123;    /** Save all received messages for later debugging purpose. */
};

Inside a worker thread a Windows message gets posted to the main thread (multiple times). The thread runs for several seconds to make sure it's not dying too early.
PostThreadMessage(mainThreadId, 0x1234, 456, 789);

When I run the DLL API from a console app, the Windows messages are received correctly. When I run it from the Delphi application, no events are getting through. No clue yet what's the reason behind that ...
On the other hand, receiving QEvents in main thread works fine even when called inside the Delphi app.
class QtMainApp  : public QApplication {

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtMainApp(
            int         argc,
            char        * argv[])
        : QApplication(argc, argv) {
    }
    
    ~QtMainApp() = default;

    int                     eventCount = 0; /** Counts all events incoming to notify(). */

protected:
    /** Receives all QEvents and filters for user events. */
    bool
    notify(
            QObject     * receiver,
            QEvent      * event) override;

    if (event->type() == QEvent::User) {
        /* this works */
        eventCount++;
    }
};

The user-defined event is derived from QEvent:
/**
 * User-defined QEvent which has a payload attached.
 */
class QUserEvent : public QEvent {

public:
    QUserEvent(
            const QString   & text)
        : QEvent(QEvent::User)
        , text(text) {
    }
    ~QUserEvent() = default;

public:
    QString     text;
};

The event is posted from the worker thread:
QtMainApp::postEvent(qApp /*receiver*/, new QUserEvent{"this is a test"});

The event count goes up for each event sent.
I wonder why QEvents work, but Windows messages don't. Because I assumed that QEvent  use the Windows message system in the background to allow passing the thread boundaries. QApplication::exec() is never called, so the Qt event loop is not or running, nor is it polled.
Any ideas or links on how it works?
Thank you for reading,
Paul
EDIT 1:
The QApplication instance is required by classes like QImage and QFontDatabase which are used in DLL.
Signal / slot mechanism is not used because the runtime binding feature of callbacks is not required. Also, the additional MOC / QObject subclassing harms compilation time.
EDIT 2:
It seems that Qt puts QEvent instances into a message queue from which the receiver can read them. The receiving thread is then woken up (at least on MS Windows) by sending a message (PostMessage) addressed to an invisible window created on start-up (see qt_create_internal_window() in qeventdispatcher_win.cpp). The method qt_internal_proc() (same file) receives the Windows message.
That leads me to (the unproven) conclusion that to be able to receive Windows messages, registering such a window with a callback manager is required.

You do not need all this in Qt for the most of cases. And especially easy to send a message to the main thread. It is a Qt event loop. Just connect a signal to slot and then emit the signal from any thread to any thread. Read on signal-slot. For the interthread messaging do no use direct connection though.

Sorry for not mentioning: The QApplication code is required for further features like QImage and QFontDatabase.
Signal / slot is actually what I'm trying to get away from: The additional MOC / QObject subclassing harms compilation time.

Using PostThreadMessage() can work in a Delphi GUI app. Use the TApplication(Events).OnMessage event to receive them. Or you can use (Post|Send)Message() to the TApplication.Handle window and use the TApplication.HookMainWindow() method to receive them. Personally, I would have the DLL expose a callback that runs in the worker thread, and let the GUI app prove a handler that decides how it wants to post to the main thread. For instance, using TThread.Synchronize() or `TThread.Queue() instead of thread/window messages. The DLL should not post directly to the GUI
